# Electron: Sending app.getPath data from the main process to the renderer process

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, desktop-application

Given:

```js
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: false,
  contextIsolation: true,
  sandbox: true,
}
```

I need to access the result of [`app.getPath("appData")`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/api/app#appgetpathname) in my renderer process.

`app.getPath("appData")` only works in the main process.

`contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld()` only works on the preload script.

How do I expose the result of `app.getPath("appData")` to the renderer if the preload script can't access `app.getPath("appData")` and the main process can't access `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

- set up the preload script to call `exposeInMainWorld` to put a Promise-invoking function on the window. When invoked, make a request to the main process
- set up the main process to respond to requests from the preload script with the desired info

```
// Main process:
ipcMain.handle('getPath', () => app.getPath("appData"));
```

```
// Preload:
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    getPath: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('getPath')
});
```

```
// Renderer:
window.electronAPI.getPath()
  .then((appDataPath) => {
    // ...
  })
  .catch(handleErrors);
```

The preload script essentially acts as a bridge between the sandboxed page and the privileged main process - often, most of an application's logic will live either in the main process or the renderer, and the preload only bridges them.

For a more generalized approach of sending messages from the renderer to main (possibly while waiting for a response), I've found the following to work pretty well:

```
// Preload:
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    sendMessageToMainProcess: (channel: string, payload: unknown) => ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, payload),
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But isn't your last bit of code insecure? It mentions this on here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it depends on the context. If you're going to be including untrustworthy code on the page *and* your main process has handlers that need to be gated - sure, set up something more selective. But if the code that you run is either yours or trustworthy, or none of the handlers expose anything sensitive, *and* you need many different communication channels to the main process - then I don't see what coding (and typing) each of those channels individually would help with, other than introduce an annoying amount of boilerplate.